# Controlling mysql first record

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I am working on slideshow. I want to change html tag clas to item active when the first record is fetched from the database and for the rest of the records the class should change back to item.

```
$RelatedTo=1;
$queryservices = "SELECT services.`ServId`, `Title`, `Details` from services WHERE RelatedTo=?";
$statement = $connection->prepare($queryservices);
$statement->bind_param('i', $RelatedTo);
$statement->execute();
$statement->bind_result($ServId,$Title, $Details,$RelatedTo,$Id,$Name,$GalServId);
while($statement->fetch()){
$numrows=0;
$numrows = $statement->num_rows;
echo "
<div "; if ($numrows== 1)
            { 
            echo "class=\"item active\""; 
            }
            else{ echo "class=\"item\"";
            } 
             echo">
    <a href=\"#\">
    <img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"/skylight_decor/img/ServiceImg/".$Name."\" alt=\"\"/>
    </a>
</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `$numrows` to a `boolean`. In the first iteration `$numrows` is `true`, and at the end of the while you change the value to `false`. See the example:

```
    $RelatedTo=1;
    $queryservices = "SELECT services.`ServId`, `Title`, `Details` from services WHERE RelatedTo=?";
    $statement = $connection->prepare($queryservices);
    $statement->bind_param('i', $RelatedTo);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($ServId,$Title, $Details,$RelatedTo,$Id,$Name,$GalServId);

    $numrows = true;

    while($statement->fetch()){
    echo "
    <div "; if ($numrows)
                { 
                echo "class=\"item active\""; 
                }
                else{ echo "class=\"item\"";
                } 
                 echo">
        <a href=\"#\">
        <img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"/skylight_decor/img/ServiceImg/".$Name."\" alt=\"\"/>
        </a>
    </div>";

$numrows = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that's working but the problem is that it's getting one extra record. Why?

Comment: @user3811350 can you test your query in phpmyadmin and see if you get the records that you expected?

Comment: it's working mysql it's working. I have three photos and one service and i have used inner join $queryservices = "SELECT services.`ServId`, `Title`, `Details`,`Id`, `Name`, gallery.`ServId` from services inner join gallery on services.ServId=gallery.ServId
 WHERE services.ServId=?";

Comment: @user3811350 when you use while($statement->fetch()) is not possible that you get one extra record at least that your sql query not work as you expected